# group by returns extra row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a query like below

```
select name,
          sum(...) col1, 
          sum(...) col2,
          sum(...) col3
From 
          table1
group by name;
```

This query is returning 3 rows

Now suppose I want one more column say department in above query, I modified it as follows. Now the problem is, it is returning 4 rows(One extra row) which I do not want.

Now able to get the logic behind this and whether is it possible to get same result which I had without group by department and still getting its values. Please help.

```
select name, department
          sum(...) col1, 
          sum(...) col2,
          sum(...) col3
From 
          table1
group by name, department;
```

Comment: this must mean that the DEPARTMENT exists within 2 NAMES, so the SUM becomes the total for the DEPARTMENT within the NAME.

Comment: Share your dataset for better understanding, i believe you are facing issue as mentioned by @davegreen100 in comment

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list_agg()` to concatenate departments:

```
select name, sum(x1) col1, sum(x2) col2, sum(x3) col3,
       listagg(department,', ') within group (order by department) departments
  from table1 group by name order by name;
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77253/1)</sup>

To show only distinct departments for each name aggregate data at first:

```
select name, sum(col1) col1, sum(col2) col2, sum(col3) col3,
       listagg(department,', ') within group (order by department) departments
  from (
    select name, department, sum(x1) col1, sum(x2) col2, sum(x3) col3
      from table1 group by name, department)
  group by name order by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for a given name, there is more then one department. There's no way to aggregate the results to get around this - at best, you'd need to have multiple values of `department` in the resultset row's column. This is always tricky. On MS SQL, you could do something like `(select department from table1 t where t.name = table1.name for xml raw)`, but I'm not sure if there's something that could be used like this in Oracle. Maybe a custom aggregate function?

If you don't strictly care about this, doing something like `max(department)` instead of grouping by it might work. But do understand the results you are getting - it might be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query:

```
select name,
       listagg(department, ', ') within group (order by name),
       sum(...) col1, 
       sum(...) col2,
       sum(...) col3
  from table1
  group by name;
```

Comment: Posted the answer to find that Ponder Stibbons added a similar answer few seconds back...